# trying to put a line break (carriage return?) through tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have created a python script for sending a tweet out to twitter. I am having an issue with sending a carriage return / line break. Normally I would like the command \n in python but this doesn't work with tweepy and it send the text to twitter including the \n.

The end of my script looks like this:

```
phrase = "Hello World! \n I am sending a tweet from a bot!"    
api.update_status(phrase)
```

and the result on twitter is:

```
Hello World! \n I am sending a tweet from a bot!
```

and what I want is:

```
Hello World!    
I am sending a tweet from a bot!
```

How can I do this with my script?

Answer (score 2):

That's unusual, what you tried *should* be working.

For whatever reason, it doesn't seem to be. This should work instead:

```
phrase = """
Hello World!

I am sending a tweet from a bot!
"""    
api.update_status(phrase)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the late response, but I was struggling with this until I figured out  the solution:

```
create_tweet(text=message.replace("\\n", "\n"))
```

That replaces the escaped newline with a true newline character.
I haven't tested it out with `api.update_status`, but it still should work nevertheless.